# Accessing the quickadmin panel after installation

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have downloaded and installed the quickadmin project from github:
https://github.com/laraveldaily/quickadmin

I have followed the following steps for installation succesfully:

```
1.Install the package via composer require laraveldaily/quickadmin.
2.Add Laraveldaily\Quickadmin\QuickadminServiceProvider::class, to your config\app.php providers.
3.Configure your .env with the correct database information
4.Run php artisan quickadmin:install and fill the required information.
5.Register middleware 'role' => \Laraveldaily\Quickadmin\Middleware\HasPermissions::class, in your App\Http\Kernel.php at $routeMiddleware
```

All these steps have completed successfully. But the last step which says,
Access QuickAdmin panel by visiting http://yourdomain/admin.
is the one I am confused with. How do I access the my quickadmin panel? What does yourdomain mean?
Sorry for the beginner question, I am not able to figure it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in to this:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/valet

then when you have figured that out you can go to yourproject.test/admin

.. i guess

ps.

this is if you have mac, if not then this is for you: https://github.com/cretueusebiu/valet-windows

ds.

Comment: Thank you for the response! Just found out I can use php artisan serve, and then log on to quickadmin panel by navigating to localhost:8000/admin